# How to execute pickle serialize class a remote host with Python

Tags: python

I used Pickle to serialize a Python object locally, and after the deserialization on the remote host, an error was reported.suggesting that I ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'.
I want the remote host to not see my source file while executing my function

> This is my file structure
>
> ```
>  |plugins/
>    |one/
>       |--test1.py
>  |main.py
> ```

The file is located in the plugins directory

```
class Plugin:
    def start(self):
        pass
o=Plugin()
import pickle
pickle.loads(o)
```

This is the code that is executed remotely

```
import pickle,requests
result=requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/').content
o=pickle.loads(result)
o.start()
```

Remote host throws an exception

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bc409313ddfa> in <module>
----> 1 o=pickle.loads(result)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'
```

Comment: Pickle only pickles the class and function names, and none of the code that makes up the function or class. Therefore, when unpicking, it must have access to the code that the function / class originated from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you would explain in more detail what you want to accomplish here. It seems to me as if you want to implement a protocol where arbitrary code can be executed on a remote host.

I think it is quite possible that the pickle module is not what you are looking for.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

So in order to make your example work as it is, the remote host *must* get the source of the 'plugins' module or at least the source of the 'Plugin' class.

**Update:**
As you explained in your comment, your aim *is* to execute code remotely. This cannot be done with the pickle module.

You may want to have a look at RPyC, a library for remote procedure calls and distributed-computing:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPyC
- https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I want to achieve a scenario where I have a server and multiple clients. The server publishes the function to be executed to any client. After the client is executed, the result is returned to the server, similar to a distributed system, but I am not very clear. How to use python to implement, most of them need to have executable task code on the client, but I hope that the executable code can not be seen. Can you give me an idea, maybe I have n’t thought of it yet.

Comment: I tried it out and it was great. I really needed it. I am very attentive to learn something new. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) could save your question.  It's extends the pickle.

```
dill.dump(your_class_obj, local_file)  # dump to file

dill.load(local_file) # load in other place
```